# Pivot Item Rotates and Selected One come first, Need to set Fix position to headers.

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I am using Pivot control in Universal Windows Platform. When I re-size the window and Select the second pivot-item it comes first(pivot rotates). I need this to fixed in position. Thanks in Advance.[image: Pivot A Selected]
[image: Pivot B Selected and Comes first]

Answer (score 0):

There is an official sample from [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/e13cf5dca497ad661706d150a154830666913be4/Samples/XamlPivot) that uses the `Pivot` control. And in Scenario3, it shows how to acheive a 'tab-like' visual using specially styled `Pivot`. I think this is what you want.

According to the sample, you can modify the template of `Pivot`.To modify the template of `Pivot`, we can select the "**[Pivot]**" in "**Document Outline**" and right click, then select "**Edit Template**"→ "**Edit a Copy...**".

The key point here is to find `<Grid x:Name="PivotLayoutElement">`, and then you can edit the `Grid.ColumnDefinitions` like this:

```html
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```